# How to send an email from IBM iSeries DB2 v7.1

Tags: email, db2-400

I am trying to create a trigger that sends an email based on a database event, specifically, when a record is INSERTed in a certain table, I want an email stating that fact to go to the SysAdmin.

I can successfully do the following from a SQL window in iSeries Navigator:

```
CL:SNDDST TYPE(*LMSG) 
   TOINTNET(('sysadmin@mycompany.com')) 
   DSTD('this is the Subject Line') 
   LONGMSG('This is an Email sent from iSeries box via Navigator')
```

...and an email gets sent.  Which means that the necessary SMTP stuff is there and working.

So all I'm trying to do is encapsulate this code, perhaps with some data changes (e.g. "A record has been added to the XYZ table on whatever-the-sysdate-is").  Navigator has some tantalizing examples that call CL to do some plain-vanilla things, but no clue as to how to make it work in a trigger.  I know how to write triggers that do "database stuff", but not this CL stuff.  And this is iSeries DB2, so I don't have access to UTL_MAIL.

I know next to nothing about CL, DDS or other iSeries internals... I would prefer not to have to create an external Java program, but will do that as a last resort...but even then, I'm having a hard time finding straightforward examples.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, note that SNDDST isn't the best choice for internet mail from the IBM i.  Basically, SNDDST is a relic from the SNADS networking days that IBM hacked into supporting SMTP emails.  There are free alternatives, or if you're reasonably current on fixes for 7.1 then you should have the Send SMTP E-mail (SNDSMTPEMM) command available.

The Run SQL Scripts window of iNav does indeed support CL commands using the CL: prefix.  But that's not the same thing as having the query engine itself understand CL.

The CL: prefix isn't going to work inside an SQL trigger.

You could however,[use the QCMDEXC stored procedure](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaik/rzaikclcmd.htm)  to call a CL command.  But I wouldn't necessarily call that the best option.

The IBM i supports using "external" stored procedures and triggers.  Theoretically, you could use a CL program that invokes the SNDSMTPEMM command directly.  But given you desires to include data from the table, I wouldn't recommend that approach as you'd be tied to the table structure.

Instead, create your own UTLMAILSND CL program that invokes SNDSMTPEMM.  Then defined the UTLMAILSND program as an [external stored procedure](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcrtpef.htm) (you can even give it a longer SQL name of UTIL_MAIL_SEND).

Now you can call your UTIL_MAIL_SEND() procedure from your SQL trigger.

Comment: Thanks -- I think I will go the route of a plain external CL program.  This is the first (and hopefully only?) time I'll have to do this, although once the concept is proved, requests for the same functionality elsewhere will probably start coming out of the woodwork.  I was hoping for an answer that kept me out of green-screen CL programming (which is completely foreign to me), but if that's the only way to get it done, oh well...

Answer (score 0):

You need to try the SNDSMTPEMM command.  It's like sliced bread compared to `SNDDST TYPE(*LMSG)`  It supports HTML too which makes for a lot of fun.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I used SNDSMPTEMM (skipping the html for now...).

One big note, however: using this command in a CL program doesn't work when being called from SQL. I had to change it to a CLLE program.

So the final answer is as follows: a) an INSERT trigger on the table in question, which calls: b) an (external) PROCEDURE created in the database, which in turn calls: c) the compiled CLLE program object. Works like a charm.

p.s. I create the whole body of the email in the INSERT trigger, and pass it along, eventually to the CLLE program.  This allows me to have just this one CLLE program to report on any INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE anywhere in the database.